# Logging results of fork() in C to file to see results

Tags: c, file, logging, output, fork

I'm trying to get the results of each run of the program (both the parent and child). The results print once on the screen and only once in a file. I can't seem to get two unique files created (one representing parent and one representing child). I'm not sure if getpid() is the effective way to separate parent and child identification. What could I be doing wrong?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

    static char *app1="/path/to/app1";
    static char *app;
    static pid_t forky=-1;

    void otherfunction(){
      int aflag=1;
      //do something
      if (aflag==1){
        //run app 1
        app=app1;
        printf("Starting fork\n");
        forky=fork();
      }
    }

int main(){
      char dat[40000],test[10000];
      sprintf(dat,"Exec start\nFORKY = %d\nPID = %d\nPPID = %d\n",forky,getpid(),getppid());
      sprintf(test,"/TEST%d",getpid());
      int h=open(test,O_WRONLY|O_CREAT);
      write(1,dat,strlen(dat));
      write(h,dat,strlen(dat));
      close(h);
      otherfunction();
      return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating the file before you call fork. The fork is the last thing you do and then both processes just return 0.

Answer (score 0):

As specified in [fork's man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork), the process created by calling `fork` is a copy of the parent process except for some specific differences, and this child process starts execution as if resuming from after the call to `fork`. So, it's kind of like you get two returns from `fork`, one for the parent and one for the child. So, it looks like you ask two questions here:

**How to differentiate parent and child**

Again, the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) mentions that fork will return the child's pid in the parent process and 0 for the child process so the following code sample will get you distinguished output from both:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0)
        printf("Hello from child!!!\n");
    else if(pid > 0)
        printf("Hello from parent!!!\n");
    else
        printf("Wow, fork failed!!!");

    return 0;
}
```

**Obtaining separate files for each process**

As mentioned above, both processes resume from *after* the call to `fork`, so the files must be created *after* calling to fork. In your example you are calling `otherfunction` last in main, so `fork` is pretty much the last call in both processes.

The following is an example that will give you different files with different content for each process, as well as print in `stdout` for each process. The usage of `getpid` here is just so you can actually check what the man page says.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pid_t pid = fork();
    int h;
    char *test;
    char dat[100];

    if (pid == 0)
        test = "child";
    else if(pid > 0)
        test = "parent";
    else
        test = "failed";

    h = open(test,O_WRONLY|O_CREAT);
    sprintf(dat, "%s | fork returned = %d | my_pid = %d\n", test, pid, getpid());
    write(1,dat,strlen(dat));
    write(h,dat,strlen(dat));
    close(h);
}
```